# 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED after MQ Classes for Java Upgrade

Tags: java, ibm-mq

We have an app using MQ classes for Java v6 to pop messages from MQ. There is no authorization in place other than network security limiting access to the MQ server and its ports. This app also must read from a different MQ server that requires a client certificate and TLS1.3. To get this to work, we had to upgrade to the latest MQ classes for Java (9.3 or so). Once we do this, the app can no longer read from the first MQ server. It gets 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED. We did not change the MQ server nor any of the code that reads from it. The only change is updating to the newest library.

IBM's docs mention that this may happen because they have "clarified" authentication.

Has anyone had this issue and been able to resolve it? It is going to delay the product launch of the second app feature unless we resolve it.

Updated MQ classes for Java library from 6.0 to 9.3. I expected existing connectivity to continue to work.  I get 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED.

Comment: Did you get your connection working?

Answer (score 0):

While having no security is not a recommended security practice, the reason it is not working is likely that the old libraries were sending an empty username which if using an older MQ server version (or a newer MQ server version configured like a older version) would allow the SVRCONN channel to run as the privileged user (mqm for example on Unix/Linux systems).  it could also be possible that the app was configured to send a specified user id and now that user id is being sent in the MQCSP (not the way it would be sent in v6).

It is unclear if you upgraded just the IBM MQ client jar files to the newer version or also a local queue manager, I will assume just the IBM MQ client jar files.

Most likely you just need to turn on compatibility mode to get back the prior behavior, review the following page for the different methods to accomplish this:

[Connection authentication with the Java client](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=authentication-connection-java-client)

The non-intrusive way to do this is to pass the following Java system property at start up:

```
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=N
```